# Не отображаются активные вопросы в "избранном"

Tags: дефект, избранное

На мете, когда в избранному вижу цифру (означающую активность), то не вижу какие из вопросов активны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншота (и если поскороллить ниже), то нет никаких выделенных вопросов. Данный дефект вижу только на мете, на основном сайте не наблюдал.

Comment: Допускаю, что дело может быть в стилях. В html коде порыться не пробовали?

Comment: Может быть, но на основном сайте этой проблемы нет. Может тогда кто-то просто сравнит соответствующие стили. Хотя, хорошая мысль, спасибо, как будет время, может займусь.

Comment: @alexolut Да вообще что-то не вижу ничего в HTML. Как будто выделенных вопросов и быть не должно.